# How can i write a customized TestNGCucumberRunner with the latest io.cucumber.cucumber-testng version 4.2.6

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I am trying to write a custom TestNGCucumberRunner (for the latest version cucumber 4.2.6) where I can filter the list of cucumberfeatures based on runtime arguments, in the getFeatures() method.

All the examples online are explained with info.cukes 1.2.5 version, where all the dependent classes and methods were public

I have never written a testrunner before. Can any one help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First -*** Update POM.xml with correct set of io.cucumber dependencies as per v 4.2.6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

***Second -*** Customize TestNGRunner class as per your framework need

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional.BaseSteps;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest extends Hooks {

}
```

***Third*** - Implement Hooks.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class Hooks extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser);
    }
}
```

Note - I have not implemented this way. But as per my best knowledge, it may work. Please check and share your experience.

***Fourth -*** Update TestNG.xml under /src/test/resources/ as per your TestNGRunner Class and framework need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

    <test thread-count="1" name="Test" parallel="tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner.RunCukeTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

***Fifth -*** You shall be all set to run automation suite using TestNG in any of the following ways

```
 -    Run TestNG.xml directly from IDE 
 -    From CMD - mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testng.xml
 -    From POM.xml - Using Surefire Plugin

<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>selenium-tests</id>
      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
               <configuration>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>     
         </plugins>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```